# Inserting lines at the beginning and end of multiple files

Tags: perl, command-line

I have about 2000 files that I need lines added to the beginning and end of.

I need these lines at the beginning of each files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

I also need this to be the last line of each file:

```
</urlset>
```

These files are all in the same folder and are all .xml files.

I'm thinking the best and fastest way to do this would be via command line or perl but am really not sure.  I've seen a few tutorials on doing this but I think all the characters that are in the lines I need inserted are whats messing it up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), I only use a [glob](/questions/tagged/glob) and a simple [concatenation](/questions/tagged/concatenation).

```
for file in *.xml; do
    {
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'
        cat "$file"
        echo "</urlset>"
    } > /tmp/file$$ &&
    mv /tmp/file$$ "$file" 
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for Perl...

Version that loads entire file into memory:

```
perl -i -0777pe'
   $_ = qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n}
      . qq{<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n}
      . $_
      . qq{</urlset>\n};
' *.xml
```

Version that only reads one line at a time:

```
perl -i -ne'
   if ($.==1) {
      print qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n},
            qq{<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n};
   }
   print;
   if (eof) {
      print qq{</urlset>\n};
      close(ARGV);
   }
' *.xml
```

Note: `eof` is not the same as `eof()`.
Note: `close(ARGV)` causes the line numbers to reset.

Comment: What means -0777pe ? Is it for changing `$/` ?

Comment: `-0777 -p -e`. `-0777` does indeed change `$/`, causing Perl to treat the entirety of a file as one line. See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 3):

For Perl you can use [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) to do it easily.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings  qw(FATAL utf8);
use open      qw(:std :utf8);

use Tie::File;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
  # Skip to the next one unless the current $arg is a file.
  next unless -f $arg;

  # Added benefit: No such thing as a file being too big
  tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $arg or die;

  # New first line, will become the second line
  unshift @file, '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

  # The real first line.
  unshift @file, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

  # Final line.
  push @file, '</urlset>';

  # All done.
  untie @file;
}
```

Save to whatever you want, then run it as `perl whatever_you_named_it path/to/files/*`.

Comment: I like this very readable solution, even though it is rather slow due to the overhead of `Tie::File`.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed -i -e '1i<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' \
-e '$a</urlset>' *.xml
```